# Converting from SHP into TXT file using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point, coordinates

I'm working with many shp file point format with geometry attributes like this:

[image]

But I need convert it into such format in textfile like below:

[image]

Are there any ways to arrange my shapefiles format into coordinates separated by comma orderly using PyQGIS or another python script.

Since I'm still learning with Python, I try to learning by doing.

Comment: You want to write all the values of the "ycoord" field one after the other in a .txt file?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37564/ogr-shapefile-to-csv-using-python-to-get-wkt-for-multipart-polys

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write all the values of the `ycoord` field into a .txt file, you can execute the following code in the Python Console of QGIS (change the parameters with your own):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # your layer
features = layer.getFeatures() # features of your layer

with open('C:/Users/v.bre/Downloads/ycoord.txt','w') as my_file: # Change the path of the file
    for feature in features:
        my_file.write(str(feature["ycoord"]) + '\n') 

    my_file.close() # close the file
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: I think it's more : `my_file.write(str(feature["ycoord"]) + "," + str(feature["xcoord"]) + ", ")`.

Comment: Yes, I realized that afterwards, I proposed an alternative, I thought that he would adapt the code if necessary. The outline is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BulkVectorExport plug-in](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BulkVectorExport/) to save layers in your project to `CSV` (or to other output formats). In this case all columns are written to the text file, but you can use the Python sources of the plug-in to customize. Look for *run* function in [`bulkvectorexport.py`](https://github.com/zsiki/bulkvectorexport/blob/master/bulkvectorexport.py#L204), the `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` function ([in line 204](https://github.com/zsiki/bulkvectorexport/blob/master/bulkvectorexport.py#L204)) has an *attributes* parameter to select attributes to export ([see the PyQGIS API Documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions.attributes)).

There are [some examples here](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat/).